# Reading JSON from Firebase and ending up with an array of all the same values [Swift]

Tags: arrays, json, swift, firebase, append

Okay I have a JSON database in Firebase formatted as such (well at least below is a snippet of it)

```
   "Trips" : {
        "-KnH34F_WZYNHMsTzj0X" : {
          "Distance" : 500,
          "Transport" : "Walk",
          "TripName" : "Work"
        },
        "-KnH3_WnQaD3piXI7oFf" : {
          "Distance" : 900,
          "Transport" : "Bike",
          "TripName" : "Test"
        },
        "-KnH7yi4bl2oM6LobPQv" : {
          "Distance" : 50,
          "Transport" : "Bike",
          "TripName" : "Test"
        },
```

I then have the below code to sift through the data and append it into an array of Trip objects.

```
 Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(user).child("Trips").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if dict?["Distance"] != nil {
                self.commuteBuilder.distance = dict?["Distance"] as? Double
            }
            if dict?["TripName"] != nil {
                self.commuteBuilder.title = dict?["TripName"] as? String
            }
            if dict?["Transport"] != nil {
                self.commuteBuilder.transportType = (dict?["Transport"] as? String)
            }

         //   if self.commuteBuilder.isFilled(){

                self.commuteArray.append(self.commuteBuilder)
                print("Append")


                self.commuteTableView.reloadData()
     //       }


        })
```

When I set breakpoints the new commuteBuilder object correctly fills the data but once appended, every value in the commuteArray ends up having the same data as the last object added to it.

So in the above example the array would end up with 3 entries but they would all have TripName: Test and Distance: 50 and Transport "Bike"

I also know the codes messy, I've been struggling with it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.commuteArray.append(self.commuteBuilder)
```

this is I think where it goes wrong. Make a temporary commuteBuilder object. Put the retrieved data in that temp object. Append that temp object to your array.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I managed to fix it by declaring the commuteBuilder inside the function instead of declaring it outside the function. I am guessing this would have to do with how arrays are built. Declaring it outside the function its just one object and the array simply points to it several times instead of creating different objects.